Displaying a custom product field in orders using the Multivendor plugin
Using the code from here, I added a custom field element on the admin order pages (uses CRUD methods, works with a high-performance order store).
I also managed to add a custom field for the vendor dashboard, for the MultivendorX plugin:

There is a display of the field value (which is added from the admin side)
A field for entering the value and a button.

What this code does not do: I cannot get the field value to be saved when clicking on the button and updated from the supplier dashboard.
Any help please
//Add a custom field
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'add_order_item_custom_field', 10, 2);
function add_order_item_custom_field($item_id, $item)
{
    // Targeting line items type only
    if ($item->get_type() !== 'line_item') return;

    $post_key = 'markcode_oitem_' . $item_id;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => $post_key,
        'label' => __('Product label code', 'text_domain'),
        'description' => __('Enter product label code here.', 'text_domain'),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'class' => 'woocommerce',
        'value' => $item->get_meta('_mark_code'),
    ));
}

// Change displayed label for specific order item meta key
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 20, 3);
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key($display_key, $meta, $item)
{
    if (is_admin() && $item->get_type() === 'line_item' && $meta->key === '_mark_code') {
        $display_key = __('Product marking code', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $display_key;
}

// Save the custom field value (Compatible with HPOS)
add_action('woocommerce_before_save_order_item', 'save_order_item_mark_code_value', 100);
function save_order_item_mark_code_value($item)
{
    $post_key = 'markcode_oitem_' . $item->get_id();

    if (isset($_POST[$post_key])) {
        $item->update_meta_data('_mark_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST[$post_key]));
    }
}

// Add the field to the vendor's dashboard
add_action('mvx_vendor_order_item_meta_after', 'mvx_add_order_item_mark_code', 10, 2);
function mvx_add_order_item_mark_code($item, $order)
{
    $post_key = 'markcode_oitem_' . $item->get_id();
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => $post_key,
        'label' => __('Product label code', 'text_domain'),
        'description' => __('Enter product label code here.', 'text_domain'),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'class' => 'woocommerce',
        'value' => $item->get_meta('_mark_code'),
    ));
}

// Adding a custom field to products in a seller's order
add_action('mvx_vendor_dash_after_order_itemmeta_table', 'mvx_add_custom_field_to_vendor_order_item', 10, 3);
function mvx_add_custom_field_to_vendor_order_item($item_id, $item, $product)
{
    $post_key = 'markcode_oitem_' . $item_id;
    $mark_code = get_post_meta($item->get_id(), '_mark_code', true);
?>
    <div class="smarkcode">
        <input type="text" name="mark_code" id="mark_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mark_code; ?>" data-item-id="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
        <button class="button btn btn-default save-mark-code" data-item-id="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">Save</button>
    </div>
<?php
}

